# What's the different between fasttext skipgram and word2vec skipgram?

Tags: nlp, fasttext

Given a sentence 'hello world', the vocabulary is

{hello, world} + {<hel, hell, ello, llo>, <wor, worl, orld, rld>},

for convenience, just list all 4-gram.

In my comprehension, the word2vec skipgram will maximize

[image]

What will fasttext skipgram do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr

The optimization criterion is the same, the difference is how the model gets the word vector.

### Using formulas

Fasttext optimizes the same criterion as the standard skipgram model (using the formula from the [FastText paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.04606.pdf)):

[image]

with all the approximation tricks that make the optimization computationally efficient. In the end, they get this:

[image]

There is a sum over all words *w<sub>c</sub>* and approximate the denominator using some negative samples *n*. The crucial difference is in the function *s*. In the original skip-gram model, it is a dot product of the two word embeddings.

However, in the FastText case, the function *s* is redefined:

[image]

Word *w<sub>t</sub>* is represented as a sum of all n-grams *z<sub>g</sub>* the word consist of plus a vector for the word itself. You basically want to make no only the word, but also all its substrings probable in the given context window.

Comment: Thank you, that is the difference while using negative sampling, but the paper does not give the detail about Hierarchical Softmax,

Comment: FastText only uses negative sampling. However, it would be the same with hierarchical softmax, you would just replace the dot product of embeddings with the _s_ function.

Comment: I don't think only negative sampling is used. In its source code, you can chose softmax, negative sampling or hierarchical softmax to train the model.

Comment: Oh, cool. The paper only mentions results with negative sampling, so I would assume, it had the best results.